# Consider this estimator of a cumulative distribution function. Can you tell me if it is consistent? What about the assymptotic distribution?

Tags: distributions, estimation, econometrics, cumulative-distribution-function, consistency

This is an estimator of a cdf of F(x) of a iid random sample x1, x2, ..., xn of observations. 
[image]

My question is if for a given value of x, this estimator is consistent. And how can you derive the assymptotic distribution of this estimator?

Comment: It has a Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As sample size $n$ becomes larger, the empirical CDF (ECDF) based on a random sample approaches the CDF of the population population from which the distribution is chosen.

*Demonstration in R.* First, with a sample of $n = 20,$ then with a sample of $n = 200$ from the distribution
$\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=\alpha = 5, \mathrm{rate}=\lambda = 1/10).$ (Larger sample sizes are considered subsequently.)

```
set.seed(514)  # for reproducibility
x = rgamma(20, 5, .1)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  14.35   33.81   44.46   52.95   60.22  135.63 
mean(x <= 40)
[1] 0.4
plot(ecdf(x));  rug(x)
 curve(pgamma(x, 5, .1), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

Notice that the proportion of observations in the
sample less than or equal to 40 is 0.4. Also, the
CDF of the population at 40 is $F_X(X \le 40) = P(X \le 40) = 0.3712.$

```
pgamma(40, 5, .1)
[1] 0.3711631
```

[image]

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rgamma(500, 5, .1)
summary(x)
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
9.901  34.230  45.971  50.273  60.917 163.680 
mean(x <= 40)
[1] 0.368

plot(ecdf(x))
 curve(pgamma(x, 5, .1), add=T, col="orange", lwd=3)

set.seed(123)
mean(rgamma(10^4, 5, .1) <= 40)
[1] 0.3727
```

With $n = 500$ observations the ECDF at 40 is 0.368,
closer to 0.3712, than above with $n = 20.$

[image]

Without a summary and a plot, we can see that
for $n=10\,000$ the value of the ECDF at $x=40$ is still closer to $F_X(40).$

```
set.seed(123)
mean(rgamma(10^4, 5, .1) <= 40)
[1] 0.3727
```

And very close indeed for $n=1\,000\,000:$

```
set.seed(1492)
mean(rgamma(10^6, 5, .1) <= 40)
[1] 0.371313
```

Finally, noting the hint in @whuber's Comment, I'll let you find the distribution of the ECDF at $x = 40$ and then use the LLN to show that the ECDF at $x = 40$ converges to the $F_X(40).$

*Note:* The test statistic $D$ of the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) of goodness of fit
of a sample to a particular distribution is the maximum vertical discrepancy between the ECDF of the sample and the CDF of the distribution. The [Brownian Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) is used to [obtain the distribution](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/37302/18-175Spring-2005/NR/rdonlyres/1974B061-49AB-4653-9696-1F5CDB1B690D/0/lecture29.pdf) of the K-S test statistic $D.$